# Pivot function without manually typing values in `for in`?

Tags: amazon-redshift

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FROM_clause-pivot-unpivot-examples.html) provides an example of using the pivot() function.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT partname, price FROM part) PIVOT (
    AVG(price) FOR partname IN ('prop', 'rudder', 'wing')
);
```

I would like to use `pivot()` without having to manually specify each value of partname. I want all parts. I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT partname, price FROM part) PIVOT (
    AVG(price) FOR partname);
```

That gave an error. Then tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT partname, price FROM part) PIVOT (
    AVG(price) FOR partname IN (select distinct partname from part)
);
```

That also threw an error.

How can I tell Redshift to include all values of partname in the pivot?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done in a simple single query.  This would mean that the query compiler would need to work without knowing how many output columns will be produced.  I don't think it can do that.

You can do this in multiple queries - use a query to create the list of partnames and then use this to "generate" a second query that populates the IN list.  So something needs issue these queries and generated the second.  This can be some code external to Redshift (lots of options) or a stored procedure in Redshift.  This code, no matter where it exists, should understand that Redshift has a max number of columns limit - 1,600.

The Redshift docs are fairly good on the topic of dynamic SQL for stored procedures.  The EXECUTE statement will be used to fire off the second query in a stored procedure.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html